# Neo4j 2.2.2 and wrong Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

In continue to this question [Neo4j how to delete nodes recursively from some start node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714877/neo4j-how-to-delete-nodes-recursively-from-some-start-node)

I have moved to Neo4j 2.2.2 and now have a problem with one Cypher query that works fine on a previous Neo4j 2.1.7

I use Spring Data Neo4J:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} WITH d OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) DELETE d, r WITH t, r OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-() WITH t, r2, r WHERE none(x in labels(t) WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) DELETE t, r2")
void deleteDecisions(@Param("decisionsIds") List<Long> decisionsIds);
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} WITH d OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) DELETE d, r WITH t, r OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-() WITH t, r2, r WHERE none(x in labels(t) WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) DELETE t, r2; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} WITH d OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) DELETE d, r WITH t, r OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-() WITH t, r2, r WHERE none(x in labels(t) WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) DELETE t, r2; nested exception is org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to load NODE with id 227.
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl.query(CypherQueryEngineImpl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:108)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery$1.doWithGraph(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.doExecute(Neo4jTemplate.java:465)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.access$000(Neo4jTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate$2.doInTransaction(Neo4jTemplate.java:479)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.exec(Neo4jTemplate.java:476)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:431)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:409)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
```

what can be wrong ?

**UPDATED**

After debugging I have figured out that **Unable to load NODE with id 227** 227 is a child node id.. for example I have ParentNode(id=201) with a one ChildNode(with id=227). I want to delete ParentNode with all of his children. This way I need to pass into `{decisionsIds}` IDs of parent node and child node(in order [227, 201] - child first, parent next) and right now the issue is that the Cypher query unable to delete the child node with the following error **Unable to load NODE with id 227** .. but why does it work in Neo4j 2.1.7 and how to fix it in Neo4j 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT #2]

The additional information is very helpful. The issue might to be that `t` can be a deleted child node.

Try this query, which makes sure that the `t` that is used after the initial deletions is not a deleted node.

```
MATCH (d:Decision)
WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds}
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t)
DELETE d, r
WITH t, r
WHERE NOT (id(t) IN {decisionsIds})
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-()
WHERE r2 <> r
WITH t, r2
WHERE none(x in labels(t) WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision'])
DELETE t, r2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have removed "r" from the query but it doesn't help (  - MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} WITH d OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) DELETE d, r WITH t OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-() WITH t, r2 WHERE none(x in labels(t) WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) DELETE t, r2

Comment: Added this new query but still doesn't help ( @Query("MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} WITH d OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) DELETE d, r WITH t, r OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-() WHERE r2 <> r WITH t, r2 WHERE none(x in labels(t) WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) DELETE t, r2")

Comment: @cybesam, I have updated my question with more details. Could you please look into this ?

Comment: I have updated my answer again. If this does help, can you share [a console](http://console.neo4j.org/) showing this issue?

Comment: cybersam, thank You so so much !! Now everything work like a charm ! Why it was working on a Neo4j 2.1.7 ?